# Creating A Dart Duration with negative minute number does not succeed. Is there a way to avoid this bug?

Tags: dart

Below, I show several Duration creations. Instanciating a Duration with a negative hour number returns, as expected, a negative Duration. But doing it with a negative minute number returns a positive Duration. Same problem when subtracting a two minutes Duration from a one minute Duration. I am using Dart version 2.16.2 on Windows 64 bits.

```
void main() {
  print(Duration(hours: -1)); // -1:00:00.000000
  print(Duration.zero - Duration(hours: 1)); // -1:00:00.000000
  print(Duration(minutes: -1)); // 0:01:00.000000 instead of -0:01:00.000000
  print(Duration.zero -
      Duration(minutes: 1)); // 0:01:00.000000 instead of -0:01:00.000000
}
```

Comment: AFAICT, the `Duration`  with negative minutes *is* successfully created as a negative `Duration`.  I suspect that it's just a bug in `Duration.toString()`.  Calculations with the negative `Duration` should perform the computation correctly.

Comment: This looks to be https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/48841.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to determine that Duration is, in fact, negative: you obtain Duration.inMinutes.

```
void main() {
  print(Duration(hours: -1)); // -1:00:00.000000
  print(Duration.zero - Duration(hours: 1)); // -1:00:00.000000
  print(Duration(minutes: -1)); // 0:01:00.000000 instead of -0:01:00.000000
  print(Duration.zero -
      Duration(minutes: 1)); // 0:01:00.000000 instead of -0:01:00.000000

  print(Duration(minutes: -1).inMinutes); // -1
  print((Duration.zero - Duration(minutes: 1)).inMinutes); // -1
}
```